# Can I use jquery without any licensing issues?

Tags: jquery, licensing

All,

I am amazed with functionality JQuery provides and want to use it in my application.
This is an internal application which we will host for users in our company.

Rather than ending up with licensing issues, just want to confirm.

I downloaded JQuery 1.6. I am not going to modify anything from this file. I just need to use the api. Do I need to get any extra license for this? Or inform jquery team?
Also what do they mean by using MIT or GPL license? This script file has only one header right?

Thanks.

Comment: you can happily use it , lot of companies use it.

Comment: Voting to migrate to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5):

From http://jquery.org/license/ :

> The MIT License is recommended for
>   most projects. It is simple and easy
>   to understand and it places almost no
>   restrictions on what you can do with a
>   jQuery project.
>
> If the GPL suits your project better
>   you are also free to use a jQuery
>   project under that license.
>
> You don’t have to do anything special
>   to choose one license or the other and
>   you don’t have to notify anyone which
>   license you are using. You are free to
>   use a jQuery project in commercial
>   projects as long as the copyright
>   header is left intact.